# Соединить роли пользователя через запятую

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица пользователей и есть таблица ролей (еще есть таблица сопоставления пользователей и ролей). Я выполняю такой запрос, чтобы показать инфу о юзере и его ролях.

```
SELECT UserName, FirstName, LastName, CreatedOn, Name
FROM [Users] 
JOIN [UserRoles] 
    ON Users.UserId = UserRoles.UserId
JOIN [Roles]
    ON Roles.RoleId = UserRoles.RoleId
```

Но если у пользователя больше чем одна роль, тогда в ответе приходит, таблица с одинаковыми колонками для такого юзера, и различаются лишь роли.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: какой можно сделать запрос, чтобы вернулась на одного юзера с множеством ролей лишь одна строка, где эти роли будут идти через запятую или списком ?

Comment: GROUP BY(UserName) ?

Comment: @Hardc0re Добавил в конце, не работает

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В SqlServer 2017 можно воспользоваться функцией [STRING_AGG](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql):

```
SELECT
    u.UserName, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.CreatedOn,
    r.Roles
FROM [Users] u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            ur.UserId,
            Roles = STRING_AGG(r.Name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.Name ASC)
        FROM [UserRoles] ur
            JOIN [Roles] r ON r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
        GROUP BY ur.UserId
    ) r ON r.UserId = u.UserId
```

В SqlServer более ранних версий для данной цели часто используют `FOR XML` конструкцию в подзапросе, наподобие:

```
SELECT
    u.UserName, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.CreatedOn,
    Roles = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + r.Name
        FROM [UserRoles] ur
            JOIN [Roles] r ON r.RoleId = ur.RoleId
        WHERE ur.UserId = u.UserId
        ORDER BY r.Name
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM [Users] u
```

Comment: Да, вы правы, как-то так, но теперь он почему-то при таком запросе выводи в разделе Role - NULL

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, да будет возвращать `NULL` для пользователей, у которых нет ролей. Если нужна пустая строка, то используйте функцию `ISNULL`: `Roles = ISNULL(STUFF(...), '')`.

Comment: Нужен список ролей. Просто у меня сейчас у всех юзеров есть роли, но приходит NULL

Comment: @PolyakovSergey, поправка: `for xml path` -> `for xml path('')`

Comment: О !! Отлично Спасибо